# Cannot multiply and assign to int

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I am following a Unity tutorial and got this error in my Unity car game tutorial:

> BCE0051: Operator '*' cannot be used with a left hand side of type 'int' and a right hand side of type 'boolean'.

I found these last two same errors in thease line of code

```
// These variables allow the script to power the wheels of the car.
public var FrontLeftWheel: WheelCollider;
public var FrontRightWheel: WheelCollider;
public var RearLeftWheel: WheelCollider;
public var RearRightWheel: WheelCollider;
RearRightWheel.brakeTorque = 60 * Input.GetButtonDown("Jump");
RearLeftWheel.brakeTorque = 60 * Input.GetButtonDown("Jump");
```

Comment: How do you imagine multiplication of integer with boolean?

Comment: what return `Input.GetButtonDown("Jump")`? It should return _int_, but seems like it return _bool_

Comment: @Grundy, Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") is boolean.

Comment: I am new programmer in java script. I am following tutorial http://www.level-8-games.com/car-tutorial/4584660124

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even better as @General-Doomer suggested:

```
RearRightWheel.brakeTorque = Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") ? 60 : 0;
```

Ternary operator:

```
RearRightWheel.brakeTorque = 60 * (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump")?1:0);
```

Comment: I am new programmer in java script. I am following tutorial can you please visit this tutorial link? http://www.level-8-games.com/car-tutorial/4584660124

Comment: Better: `RearRightWheel.brakeTorque = Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") ? 60 : 0;`

Answer (score 1):

`Input.GetButtonDown("Jump")` returns a `boolean` - `true` or `false`. You cannot multiply a number with `true` or `false` because it is not clear what the result should be.

I think that you want to interpret `true` or `false` as `1` or `0`, so that `brakeTorque` is 60 when the button is down and 0 when it is not.

I am not familiar with Unityscript, but in vanilla JavaScript you could use the unary `+` operator to convert a boolean to a number:

```
RearRightWheel.brakeTorque = 60 * +Input.GetButtonDown("Jump");
```

If that doesn't work, you could use the ternary operator:

```
RearRightWheel.brakeTorque = 60 * (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") ? 1 : 0);
```